# Compare two columns with two different excel files find duplictates values in java

Tags: java

How to compare two columns data in two different excel files to find duplicates in Excel ?

Answer (score 1):

One way i can think of, is to read both of them using [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/) and do string comparision.

Comment: I said worst because i didnt think about the performance implications ;-)

Comment: Now i have made it diplomatically correct by saying 'one way'

Comment: but this is way find out the soluations i thnik